# Как для теста отправить 1000 запросов с binary file через Postman?

Tags: postman

Хочу сделать следующий тест для своей программы - отправить 1000 запросов с binary file через postman.

Вопрос в том, как это сделать? Мне не удалось найти способ прикрепить binary file в Postman runner. Возможно есть другие инструменты, которые можно посоветовать, но интересует в первую очередь Postman.

ОС Windows

Можно было бы попробовать сделать это на Yandex tank, но мне не удалось найти способ установить его на Windows. За подробный гайд (для человека не работающего с linux) был бы благодарен

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону newman http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/09/21/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/

Comment: Nick, попробуйте, если вам не сложно, оформить в ответ, возможно это будет полезно всем)

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Вы хотите отправить файл в запросе ?

Comment: Да. Я хочу отправить файл именно с помощью binary

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я не до конца понял проблему, но вообще это делается без хитростей.

1. Создать в коллекции необходимый запрос с body payload который
   необходим (прикрепить файл) (см. скрин) 
   [image: создание реквеста с файловым аттачем]
2. Создать test run с необходимым количеством итераций этого запроса
   [image: создание test run]
3. Run

Comment: Загвоздка именно в том, как отправить картинку в binary. А так просто создаются запросы без файла

Comment: @АксеновВладимир, просто берешь да выбираешь через UI постмана)